# pandas mix position and label indexing without chaining

Tags: pandas, slice

Since `.ix` has been [deprecated as of Pandas 0.20](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix), I wonder what is the proper way to mix lable-based, boolean-based and position-based indexing in Pandas? I need to assign values to a slice of dataframe that can be best referenced with label or boolean on the index and position on the columns. For example (using `.loc` as placeholder for the desired slicing method):

`df.loc[df['a'] == 'x', -12:-1] = 3`

obviously this doesn't work, with which I get:

`TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [-12] of <class 'int'>`

If I use `.iloc`, I get:

`NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available`

So how do I do it, without chaining, obviously to avoid chained assignment problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use .loc with the boolean indexing, and accessing the column labels via the dataframe column index with index slicing:

```
df.loc[df['a'] == 'x', df.columns[-12:-1]] = 3
```

Comment: This works, but looks embarassingly complicated compared to R unfortunately... is this really the best syntax? I have to write the name of my dataframe 3 times?

Comment: @Thomas `df.query('a == "x"').iloc[:, -12:-1] = 3` maybe?

Comment: I think this will only edit a copy and not inplace? I get a settingWithCopyWarning when trying it.

Comment: @Thomas You are correct.  This will generate a view.  And, your assignment probably will not get back to the original dataframe.  I think the original syntax is best.  In Pandas, you really can't mix label indexing with integer location indexing.

Comment: Also the time it take to execute the program with ix (mixed labels and positions), is much faster than using iloc or loc.

Answer (score 2):

maybe I should've explained clearer. I meant if your dataframe is indexed (with 0 to n), then you can use loc[] for a combination of number for rows and lable for column:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8]})
new_df
Out[10]:
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8

new_df.loc[0,'a']
Out[11]:
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `.ix` has been removed, it looks like `.loc` does the same job now. You can make a mix reference using `.loc`.

Comment: No you cannot. I gave an example and error message in my original question.