# strange error in python pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The following code gives me a `keyError: 0`.  It works if I remove the `[0]` part.

Note that what I really wanted to do is to take each sub-dataframe in the group, do some manipulation (that for examples involves calculation between rows and between columns), and return a new dataframe.  It is similar to ddply or data.table groupby operations in R.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=list('XYXYXYXY'), b=list('AABBCCDD')))
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x['b'][0])
```

Results:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-7b87ffbc2fd2> in <module>() 
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=list('XYXYXYXY'), b=list('AABBCCDD')))
----> 2 df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x['b'][0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a key error because of the `[0]`.  While it's not a perfect description, when you specify

```
df.groupby('a')
```

you're creating something like an iterator of (label, DataFrame) pairs for each grouping, and it's not til you call `apply` that some function gets applied to each of those "sub-frames".  For example,

```
for grp, frame in df.groupby('a'):
    print('Group', grp)
    print(frame)
    print()

Group X
   a  b
0  X  A
2  X  B
4  X  C
6  X  D

Group Y
   a  b
1  Y  A
3  Y  B
5  Y  C
7  Y  D
```

Using `[0]` will attempt to index by label, not integer location, and your DataFrame where `a` == `Y` is indexed with [1, 3, 5, 7].  In other words, you're trying to do:

```
df2 = df[df.a=='Y']
df2['b'][0]  # Not only is this a key error, it's also chained indexing
```

You may find this useful: [How is pandas groupby method actually working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255236/how-is-pandas-groupby-method-actually-working/45255322#45255322)

The working version of your code would be

```
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0,1])
```

But you should prefer @juanpa's solution which will be faster here.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  I was treating the pandas series as a plain array which I see now is wrong.  The reason I am doing chain indexing is I need to refer columns by name and rows by index.   Seems like the right way to do that in Series  is   `x['b'].values[0]`     Or are there better ways of doing that?  Thanks

Comment: @X.Liu `pd.Series` don't have rows and colums... they only have an index, a single one. You were working with a data-frame anyway, where **no** chained-indexing is generally *not the way*. It is always more inefficient than using `loc` or `iloc`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga    unless I am mistaken, loc / iloc doesn't allow mixed indexing  (label + position) which is what I actually need here.   In my specific case, I need to be able to do calculation between rows / columns  (like   take the difference between last value and first value of a specific column and add the last value of another column etc etc.)

Comment: There are ways around that. Don't use chained indexing. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764042/pandas-mix-position-and-label-indexing-without-chaining

Answer (score 1):

@BradSolomon explained the source of your error. However, I think what you *really want* is the following:

```
In [7]: df.groupby('a')['b'].nth(0)
Out[7]:
a
X    A
Y    A
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do like using `apply`

```
df.groupby('a').b.apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()[0])
Out[952]: 
a
X    A
Y    A
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Or try

```
df.groupby('a').b.first()
Out[960]: 
a
X    A
Y    A
Name: b, dtype: object
```